# How do I make a function of type Signal x -> x?

Tags: elm

I want to create a function that has this type :

```
 Signal x -> x
```

as an example

```
my_return : Signal x -> x
my_return x = x     -- this is the part I have wrong
```

Could I please get an example of a function that simply takes a Signal x and returns an x?

Comment: Is this a question out of curiosity or do you need `my_return` to solve another problem? If the latter (called [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)), please state your original problem. If it's curiosity and e.g. looking into terms like Monads in connection with Elm's Signals I can still answer your question, so let me know ;)

Comment: I was curious but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in Elm (and in any pure functional language).

What Elm does is providing you a way to manipulate the inputs and create a output through a thing called *lifting*.

```
lift : (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
```

So suppose we have my_return with type a -> a then we could write this

```
my_return : a -> a
my_return x = x

lift my_return input
```

Through combining all those functions, you get a program that produces output (of type Signal Element).

```
import Mouse

my_return : a -> a
my_return x = x

main : Signal Element
main = lift (asText . my_return) Mouse.position
```

Comment: I knew this but I looked in the source and noticed that lift just calls Native.lift, etc. You were right of course so I gave you the check.

Comment: There are pure functional languages that do have monadic FRP!

Comment: What I should import to use `lift`? I'm using Elm 0.15.1. Wouldn't http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal#constant be better?